# How do a for loop to this function in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have this def in my forms to customize the attrs

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ejemploForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['image'].widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={
        'id': 'Logo',
        'class': 'file', 'data-show-upload':'false', 'data-show-preview':'false',
        'name': 'logito',
        'placeholder': 'myCustomPlaceholder'})
```

I want to do that for each widget in my template, for example: 
This is my HTML file

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group">
{{form.image}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="form-group">
{{ form.image }}
</div>
</div>
 </div>
```

So for example for the first {{form.image}} I want this:

```
    'id': 'Logo',
    'class': 'file', 'data-show-upload':'false', 'data-show-    preview':'false',
    'name': 'logito',
    'placeholder': 'myCustomPlaceholder'})
```

For the second  {{form.image}} I want this :

```
    'id': 'imagen1',
    'class': 'file', 'data-show-upload':'false', 'data-show-preview':'false',
    'name': 'imagen1',
    'placeholder': 'myCustomPlaceholder'})
```

How can I do that with the previous def function?

Comment: Since they have different data I think you need to set up two fields.

Comment: Yes the problem is that the data base only has a FileField and for save I use a for loop manually.

Answer (score 0):

If all the images are from the same form, try this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">        
                {{field}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If they are from different forms, you need to do the same thing for every form.

Comment: mmm the problem is that I just have only FileField in my data base so for that reason, I repeat the  {{form.image}} in the template